# Is there a way to calculate the ratio between SD and mean over 100 samples (0-99, 1-100, 2-101 etc.) over up to 3000 observations?

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I'm working with a data set that is vertical force recorded over time during vertical jumping.

There can be up to 10000 observations.

These data are recorded at 1000 Hz.

At the beginning of each trial the jumper stands still for between 1 to 4 s (1000 to 4000 observations).

To derive jump performance metrics from the force data, it is useful to calculate the velocity of the jumper's centre of mass. To do this we first subtract their weight from force, divide this by their mass, and then integrate this using the pracma cumtrapz function.
However, how still the jumper stands during the standing still part of the jump can vary. To overcome this I've been working on using the following method:

1. calculate mean force over 100 ms (observations) to calculate weight
2. calculate the sd over the same period
3. divide sd by mean before multiplying this by 100 to get a ratio of the two as a percentage

I would then do this for each successive 100 ms (observations; 0-99, 1-100, 2-101 etc.) and locate the locate ratio. I can then use the deem 50 observations before to 50 observations after this point the 'weighing' phase.

I know how to do this in Excel and Matlab. Excel is obviously clunky the bigger the data set, while Matlab relies on users having Matlab. I'd like to replicate this in R but cannot seem to figure it out. Can anybody help please?

Example (head(force) = 759.08 758.78 759.00 759.33 758.71 759.88):

```
f <- force$Force

install.packages("runner")
library(runner)

idx <- 100

rolling_mean <- data.frame(runner(
  x = force,
  k = 100,
  f=mean
))

colnames(rolling_mean) <- "rmean"

rolling_sd <- data.frame(runner(
  x = force,  
  k = 100,
  f=sd
))
colnames(rolling_sd) <- "rsd"

n <- length(rolling_mean$rmean)
n1 <- length(rolling_sd$rsd)

test_mean <- data.frame(rolling_mean$rmean[2:n])
test_sd <- data.frame(rolling_sd$rsd[2:n])
test_ratio <- (test_sd/test_mean)*100       
min(test_ratio)
which(test_ratio == min(test_ratio))
```

Comment: You have, for example, the `rollapply` function in package zoo´, also the package `runner` for case.
It is better if you share a reproducible example of code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to best present an example.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to apply a the function described in the question to a vector's rolling window. In the example below, the rolling window length is `k = 4` but any other value can be assigned to `k`.

```r
# test data set
set.seed(2023)
n <- 1e2
x <- rnorm(n)

# function to be applied in a rolling window
f <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  100 * mean(x, na.rm = na.rm) / sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}

# two different CRAN packages can be used
window_width <- 4
r1 <- runner::runner(x, k = window_width, f = f)
r2 <- zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = window_width, FUN = f, fill = NA)

head(r1)
#> [1]         NA  -83.88843 -109.48532  -93.96480 -128.46022  -32.74476
head(r2)
#> [1]         NA         NA         NA  -93.96480 -128.46022  -32.74476

tail(r1)
#> [1]   21.34576   33.47820   11.70941  -33.67352  -28.09972 -170.63037
tail(r2)
#> [1]   21.34576   33.47820   11.70941  -33.67352  -28.09972 -170.63037

library(microbenchmark)

# runner is fastest and this is also
# true for longer vectors 'x'
mb <- microbenchmark(
  runner = runner::runner(x, k = 4, f = f),
  zoo = zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = 4, FUN = f, fill = NA)
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
#>  runner 1.3395 1.51275 1.786942 1.66560 1.93945 4.1888   100  a 
#>     zoo 2.0193 2.32965 2.740413 2.48605 2.76650 5.8601   100   b
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's incredibly helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for those who helped. I think I've come up with a solution. It turns out that the 100 ms window was far too small and would lead to all sorts of issues later in the processing that I won't bore you with here. Below I present my code:

```
# calculating mean (SD) over 1000 successive samples

# admin, importing & extracting data ----

force <- read.csv("locate_force_data.csv")      
f <- force$Force

sampleRate <- 1000 # the rate data were collected at
dt <- 1 / sampleRate
g <- 9.81
n <- length(f)

t <- 1:n
t <- t * dt

stance <- 1000 # this is the rolling average/sd 'window'

# locating some key points to enable calculation of stance ratio ----

takeoff <- which(f < 10)[1]
forceMax <- which(f == max(f[0:takeoff]))[1]
forceMin <- which(f == min(f[0:forceMax]))[1]
forceMaxStance <- which(f == max(f[0:forceMin]))[1]

# the first value is the mean over the first 1000 samples
rollMeanForce <- data.frame(rollapply(f[1:forceMaxStance],
width=stance, FUN=mean))
# the first value is the SD over the first 1000 samples
rollSDForce <- data.frame(rollapply(f[1:forceMaxStance], width=stance,
FUN=sd))

rollRatioForce <- (rollSDForce / rollMeanForce) * 100

# locating the minimum 1000 sample sd/mean ratio 
ratioMin <- min(rollRatioForce)
ratioMinLoc <- which(rollRatioForce == min(rollRatioForce))

# calculating stance metrics based on lowest stance ratio ----

stanceStart <- ratioMinLoc
stanceEnd <- ratioMinLoc + (stance-1)
stanceMean <- mean(f[stanceStart:stanceEnd])
mass <- stanceMean / g
stanceSD <- sd(f[stanceStart:stanceEnd])
stanceRatio <- (stanceSD / stanceMean) * 100

# locating start based on lowest stance ratio metrics ----

startThresholdLower <- stanceMean - (5 * stanceSD)
startThresholdUpper <- stanceMean + (5 * stanceSD)

forceMaxN <- max(f[0:takeoff])
forceMinN <- min(f[0:forceMax])
forceMaxStanceN <- max(f[0:forceMin])

# Then I'm able to locate and visualise what I'm interested in
```